# Implement.js JavaScript module pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, inheritance, modules, prototypal-class-design

I have been playing with a new JavaScript module pattern to see what I can come up with. I think it's quite powerful and wanted to know if it is something people would find useful?

I'm looking for some advice on optimisation, or possible missing features.

Quick Example:

```
var a = function(){
    this.propa = 'a';
}
var b = function(){
    this.propb = 'b'
}
var c = Function.Implement(a, b); // -> { propa: 'a', propb: 'b' }

c.__InstanceOf__(a)         // -> true
c.__InstanceOf__(b)         // -> true
c.__InstanceOf__(Function)  // -> true : every implamented object is an __InstanceOf__ Function

// more in link ...
```

SEE MORE: [Implement.js Code and Documentation](https://github.com/iamlothian/Implement.js)

```
/* Function.prototype.Implement - 0.2.1; Copyright (c) 2014, Matthew Lothian; http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT */
Function.prototype.Implement = function() {

  'use strict';

  var 
    implementContext = (Object.prototype.toString.call(this) === "[object Function]" && this.name != "Function") ? this : null
  , implamentList = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)

  /*
    The compile phase does the brunt of the work, looping through the implamentList
    and implamenting the constructor functions on the this object. 

    As well as implamenting the __isInstanceOf__ and Extend functionality in the
    context of the newly implamented object.
  */
  , compile = function(capture_args, implementContext) {

    // keep list of constructors implamented
    var implaments = [];
    var _protected = null;

    // If we are implamenting from a function bace 
    // then add it to the implaments and capture_args list
    if(!!implementContext) {
      implaments.unshift(implementContext);
      capture_args.unshift(implementContext);
    }

    // compile all constructor functions in the passed 
    // in (imp...list) capture_args into the this object
    for (var arg in capture_args) {
      if (capture_args.hasOwnProperty(arg)) {

        var fn = undefined, thisArgs = undefined
        switch (Object.prototype.toString.call(capture_args[arg])) {
          // constructor fn stand alone
          case '[object Function]':
            fn = capture_args[arg];
            break;
            // constructor fn with capture_args // don't edit capture_args array
          case '[object Array]':
            fn = capture_args[arg][0];
            thisArgs = capture_args[arg].slice(1);
            break;
        }

        // run constructor function on this object
        fn.apply(this, thisArgs);

        // remove access to the protected var scope  
        _protected = this._protected;
        delete this._protected; 

        // if constructor has prototype functions
        for (var method in fn.prototype) {

          // provide a closure for the proto funtion
          (function (fn_p) {

            // provide access to the prototype methods and pass in the protected variable _protected
            this.constructor.prototype[method] = (function(_protected) {          
              return function() {
                return fn_p.call(this, _protected);  
              }
            }); 

          }).call(this, fn.prototype[method]);

        }     

        // remember we implamented this constructor
        implaments.push(fn);

      }
    }

    // run protitype methods with the current _protected scope
    for (var method in this.constructor.prototype)
      this.constructor.prototype[method] = this.constructor.prototype[method](_protected);    

    // provide lookup check
    this.__isInstanceOf__ = function(constructor) {
      var pass = false ||
      // any empty Function Object is an derived type
      (constructor.name === "Function" && constructor.prototype.name === "Empty") ||
      // check implaments list for constructor function
      (typeof constructor === 'function' && implaments.indexOf(constructor) >= 0);
      return pass;
    };

    // provide object extend by reimplamenting this object with more constructors
    this.Extend = function() {
      var obj = Function.Implement.apply(Function, [].concat(
        capture_args,
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
      ));

      // override __isInstanceOf__ for Extended objects
      var extending = implaments;
      var base__isInstanceOf__ = obj.__isInstanceOf__;
      obj.__isInstanceOf__ = function(constructor) {

        return false ||
        // check that all implaments are met by constructor object
        ((Object.prototype.toString.call(constructor) === "[object Object]" && !! constructor.__isInstanceOf__) &&
          (function() {
            for (var imp in extending) {
              if (!constructor.__isInstanceOf__(extending[imp]))
                return false;
            }
            return true;
          })()) ||
          base__isInstanceOf__(constructor);

      };

      return obj;
    };

    // remove __safe__ flag
    delete this.__safe__;
    return this;

  };

  // run
  var base = new function() { 
    this.__safe__ = true; 
  };

  return compile.call(
      base
    , implamentList
    , implementContext
  );

};
```

At its basis, the idea is to take **multiple constructor functions** and chain compile them into a new object. A new instance checking method is provided on the implemented object that can individually identify each constructor function. Implemented objects can also be extended further by more constructors.

Some key interesting code:

*apply function constructor to `this` object*

```
fn.apply(this, thisArgs);
```

*copy prototype function from other constructors to `this` object*

```
this.constructor.prototype[method] = this.constructor.prototype[method](_protected);
```

*new `__isInstanceOf__` method based on constructor comparison*

```
this.__isInstanceOf__ = function(constructor) {
    var pass = false ||
    // any empty Function Object is an derived type
    (constructor.name === "Function" && constructor.prototype.name === "Empty") ||
    // check implaments list for constructor function
    (typeof constructor === 'function' && implaments.indexOf(constructor) >= 0);
    return pass;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. If this question is not appropriate for this site i am happy to break it down to more manageable parts.